# Вывод текста рубрики и количества статей в рубрике

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Делаю сайт на WordPress и есть такой список рубрик в сайдбаре

```
<ul class="pages_list">
    <li><a href="#"><span class="link_1">Отделочные работы.</span><span class="count_pages">45</span></a> </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="active"><span class="link_1">Строительство мостов.</span><span class="count_pages">56</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="link_1">Строительство жилых зданий.</span><span class="count_pages">23</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="link_1">Строительство обществен&shy;ных сооружений.</span><span class="count_pages">65</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="link_1">Укладка дорожного покрытия.</span><span class="count_pages">12</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="link_1">Начало повседневной работы по формированию.</span><span class="count_pages">56</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Нужно получить отдельно название рубрики, чтобы вставить в .link_1. И отдельно количество статей в рубрике, чтобы вставить в .count_pages. Как это сделать в WordPress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[get_categories()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_categories)

[wp_list_categories()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/)

[get_terms()](https://misha.blog/wordpress/get_terms.html)

И, думаю, если догуглить, будет ещё ;)

Comment: Спасибо! Сработало.